# SAS INTCK function milliseconds

Tags: sas

I have a question regarding to the `intck` function in SAS.

Can `INTCK` handle milliseconds? I read the [SAS Community Posts](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/INTCK_function_examples), but it seems that it can only handle up to seconds. What should I do if I want to calculate the time difference in milliseconds?

I am also thinking directly subtracting one time from another, such as `TIME_M - LAG_TIME`. Will this work?

UPDATE:

It seems that directly subtract will work. My time is in the format of 9:00:01.321, where the 321 is the millisecond. It seems that 9:00:01.321 - 9:00:01.320 = 0.001.

I am just not sure if this method is official.

Comment: SAScommunity, your link, is not documentation. It's the equivalent of a GitHub/Blog by superusers, but definitely not documentation.

Comment: It's hard to find the documentation on this one. Also, I posted an update ...

Comment: http://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmmvacdc&cdcVersion=9.4&docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0g056g35ez8son1sfavozh0lfb3.htm&locale=en#n1d3z2e1f8u8drn1j70702vf4q3h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INTCK` is most often used to calculate complex date and time intervals - i.e., date and time intervals that don't have a direct proportional relationship to the base date or time units (days and seconds, respectively). It can also be used to code more clearly (i.e., hours is directly proportional to seconds (*3600) but `intck('HOUR',...)` may be more clear).

As such, you're certainly welcome to add or subtract directly when using seconds or a proportion thereof (milliseconds would be one such proportion). That's how I would do it in my code.

You could also define a [custom time interval](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_intervals_sect008.htm) if you wanted to take advantage of `intck` for a readability purpose.